# How to know if string contains more than one same word

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which is like this ..`String s=and oc='LOCAL' and oc='STD' and oc='ISD' and oc='INC'`.Now as per my requirement if this string contains more than one `and` then i have to replace all other `and` with `or` except first `and` else it should be the same string only..

Please help me how to get to know about more than one `and` and how to replace all other `and` except first one.

I am trying to get this using `replace` but i am not getting it exactly..

Please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't sound like you've put much effort in, but here are 2 options:

1. Use `string.IndexOf` to get the index of your first `and`, and from there, cut the rest, and then use `string.Replace` to change `and` to `or`
2. Use linq. Split on white space. You can then have a list of words, and then you can replace all the `and`s that aren't the first to `or`.

Comment: `int i = callType.IndexOf("and");` i am getting index of first `and` now how to replace other `and` after this to `or`

Comment: well, get the substring from that end (+3, so you don't take that into the substring), and on the string you have, simply replace and with or.

Comment: Done that !Now how to put if condition to check if string contains more than one `and`..

Comment: well ...assuming you've read the documentation of [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (that's a link btw), it should be rather obvious if you'll run that on the substring you got :)

Answer (score 1):

you code do like this

```
int iCount = myString.Split( new string[] {"and"}
                           , StringSplitOptions.None )
                     .Length -1;
```

Try it on this fiddle.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/6pcnz3

Comment: ohh.. what a silly mistake i have done... thanks for correcting me @JesseGood

Comment: Ok removed -1. However, probably call `IndexOf` and then `Replace` would be better as shown in the other answer.

Comment: yeah this is also great suggestion. @JesseGood BTW, thanks for the reverse downvote vote.